# Is every algebraic structure of this sort embeddable in a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

A **convex space** is a set $X$ equipped with a function $X \times X \times [0, 1] \to X$, denoted as $(a, b, t) \mapsto a \overset{t}{+} b$, such that for all $a, b, c \in X$ and $t, t' \in (0, 1)$, the following axioms hold:

- ("identity") $a \overset{0}{+} b = a$, $a \overset{1}{+} b = b$, and $a \overset{t}{+} a = a$.
- ("associativity") $a \overset{t}{+} (b \overset{t'}{+} c) = (a \overset{\frac{t(1-t')}{1-tt'}}{+} b) \overset{tt'}{+} c$.
- ("commutativity") $a \overset{t}{+} b = b \overset{1-t}{+} a$.

(There is a short [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_space) about this type of algebraic structure. I was originally curious about it as a simple way to model real-life paint mixing, and funny enough, independently even gave it the same name.)

Let's say that a convex space $X$ is **embeddable in a vector space** if there exists a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with $X \subseteq V$ and $a \overset{t}{+} b = (1-t)a + tb$ for all $a, b \in X$ and $t \in [0, 1]$. Now my initial question was whether every convex space is embeddable in a vector space - it turns out the answer is no, and here is a counterexample: Let $X$ be the two-point set $\{x, y\}$ and define
$$a \overset{t}{+} b = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if ($a = b = x$) or ($a = x$ and $t = 0$) or ($b = x$ and $t = 1$)},\\
y & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Then $X$ is a convex space that cannot be embeddable in a vector space, for then the equation $\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}y = x \overset{\frac{1}{2}}{+} y = y$ gives $x = y$. This motivates an additional axiom:

A convex space $X$ is **faithful** if the function $t \mapsto a \overset{t}{+} b$ is injective for each pair of distinct $a, b \in X$.

Now, is this enough? That is to say, *is every faithful convex space embeddable in a vector space*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $\Delta=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2:x+y\leq 1\}$ with its usual convex space structure and let $X$ be the quotient of $\Delta$ by the equivalence relation $(x,y)\sim(x',y)$ whenever $y>0$.  It is easy to see that this equivalence relation is in fact a congruence relation with respect to taking convex combinations, so $X$ inherits a convex space structure.  It is also easy to verify that this convex space structure is faithful.  However, $X$ cannot embed in a vector space, since it has elements $a,b,c$ (namely $(0,0),(1,0),$ and $(0,1)$) such that $a\overset{t}+c=b\overset{t}+c$ as long as $t>0$ but $a\neq b$.

(In fact, this is essentially the only counterexample.  By [a theorem of Stone](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convex+space#abstract_convex_sets), a convex space embeds in a vector space iff the operations $\overset{t}+$ allow cancellation except in the trivial cases $t=0,1$.  And it is not too hard to show that if $a\overset{t}+c=b\overset{t}+c$ for some $t\neq 1$, then in fact $a\overset{t}+c=b\overset{t}+c=(a\overset{s}+b)\overset{t}+c$ for all $t>0$ and all $s$, so that any counterexample to cancellation in a faithful convex space will give rise to embedding of the counterexample $X$ above into the space.)

Comment: By the way, Stone's proof of his theorem was by a hands-on analysis of the relations on the vector space freely generated by a convex space, but I think there is a cleaner proof by a sort of Hahn-Banach theorem: you prove that if $X$ is a cancellative convex space and $Y\subseteq X$ is a subspace, then any homomorphism $f:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ can be extended to a homomorphism $X\to\mathbb{R}$.  This easily implies that homomorphisms $X\to\mathbb{R}$ separate points of $X$ so $X$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^I$ for some $I$.

Comment: To prove this extension theorem, using transfinite induction, it suffices to extend $f$ to one new generator $x$ at a time.   Then the cancellative condition can be used to say that if $x$ is not independent of $Y$, then the all the constraints that the values of $f$ on $Y$ give to the value of $f(x)$ must agree with each other (essentially by cancelling out $x$ from all the relevant convex combinations).